# How does VLSM save addresses if we can just use NAT?

Tags: nat, subnet

I understand how to configure VLSM, but I'm still confused why it would be needed if we have Network Address Translation. My understanding is that a local area network can use NAT to have a user or a large amount of users with private IP addresses, but still use a single unique public IP address for all those users.
So what if 10-242 private addresses are wasted? They are free aren't they?
Where does my logic fall apart?

-Artekis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable Length Subnet Masks was an effort to enable more *efficient* use of public address space. NAT enables us to use *fewer* public addresses, (by enabling usage of private addresses internally.)

So the two ideas aren't directly related, even though both help reduce public address space waste.

Comment: Oh this makes much more sense. Thanks a bunch!